# Can`t receive Response from server Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, readline, printwriter

I am new to Java Sockets and I tried to program a simple java app, that has a ServerSocket, accepts a Request, and turns the input String reverse. When I test the Server Socket using telnet to that port, it works! But with my Client class, it doesn't give me a response...

Code on Server which sends the Text:

```
                            System.out.println(input);
                            String output = "";
                            StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();
                            abc.append(input);
                            abc = abc.reverse();
                            abc.append("\n");
                            OutputStream outStream = b.getOutputStream();
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream);
                            out.print(abc);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
```

The Code on the Client which should.. receive the Response from the Server:

```
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input Message(q to Quit):");
            if(input.equals("q")) {
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            }
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

            pw.print(input);
            pw.flush();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( s.getInputStream())); //BufferedReader aus Socket inputStreamReader
            String line = null;
            boolean wait = true;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: As usual in a thousand questions here. You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Use `println()`, or send a line terminator after the message some other way. NB `ServerSocket` doesn't send responses.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just figured out, that the problem lies within the PrintWriter in the Client class. Instead of `pw.print()` I have to call `pw.println()` and now everything works! PrintWriter wasn't sending any Info to the Server Class without the println.

Comment: Wrong. `readLine()` doesn't return until a line terminator is sent, and `println()` sends one where `print()` doesn't. It does however send everything else, in conjunction with the `flush()`.